# Do limacons with inner loops cross the origin?

Tags: trigonometry

A limacon with my inner loop, according to my teacher, does not cross the origin. I disagree. Using the example of r=3+8cos(θ), it is trivial to calculate a point where r=0 with simple trigonometric algebra. In this case, at cos(3/8)^-1, the radius should equal zero. Is there something I am missing? I would like mathematical proof for the reason why it does, not just "it appears so on the graph," as that seems to be an error in rounding. My teacher is unable to defend his point, so an argument for either side is not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You mean $\theta = \cos^{-1}(-3/8)$, but otherwise you're correct.  I suppose there is an "origin" in the $r\theta$ plane, but that's not what most of use would call the "origin" in this situation.  In the ordinary way to understand this question, the answer is that the curve passes through the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have a better term for the point (0,0) (or any angle) in the polar plane?

Comment: No, I think everyone calls it the origin.